# Optimally add group of fields to a form and generate JSON upon submit

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, forms

The best way to dynamically add a group of fields and generate JSON based on the key-value pair when the form is submitted.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <form method="POST" id="myform">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Past Question Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pqtitle" name="pqtitle" placeholder="Type Question Here" cols="40" rows="5" style="resize:vertical;" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="course">Course Code</label>
        <select type="text" class="form-control" id="coursecode" name="coursecode" placeholder="Course"></select>
        <option></option>
      </div>
      <div id="fielda">
        <div id="fielda0">
          <!-- Text input-->
          <hr/>
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Question 1</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="question1">Question</label>
              <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="question1" name="question1" placeholder="Type Question Here" cols="40" rows="5" style="resize:vertical;" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="nt">Upload Image</label>
              <input type="file" name="file" class="filestyle" data-iconName="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="options">Options</label>
              <div data-role="dynamic-fields">
                <div class="form-inline">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <input type="radio" name="answer1" id="answer1" value="Answer">Answer
                      <span>-</span>
                      <label class="sr-only" for="option1">Option</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="option1" name="option1" placeholder="Type Option Here">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <button class="btn btn-danger" data-role="remove">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                  </button>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" data-role="add">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <!-- /div.form-inline -->
              </div>
              <!-- /div[data-role="dynamic-fields"] -->
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="slug1">Slug</label>
              <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="slug1" name="slug1" placeholder="Explain You Answer" cols="40" rows="5" style="resize:vertical;" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="point1">Point</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="point1" name="point1" placeholder="Allocate Score Here" required>
              <hr/>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <!--end field0-->
      </div>
      <!--end field-->

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-dm-2 text-right">
          <button id="add-more" name="add-more" class="btn btn-primary">Add More</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but listen to form submit, and get all them child elements with a specific attribute, or a valid name. Store it all inside an array, and JSON.stringify. Then you can send it using Ajax to wherever.

Comment: Can u be more detailed. Uploading the result is not the problem, the problem is the `JSON`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @MagikalWizard.   build your JSON from field / value pairs and after you have the complete JSON array object, I would then trigger an ajax POST passing the array to a server-side PHP page:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'save_json_file.php',
    data: {'myjsondata': your_json_array},
    success: function(msg) {
      //alert(msg);  // you could show the response from the POST here to confirm completion / success.
    }
});
```

Then in PHP you retrieve the POSTed JSON data and use file_put_contents to save it to the server:

```
$data_to_save = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
file_put_contents($data_to_save, 'newfilesaved.json');
```

Note: you may need to URL Encode the inbound JSON data

Update:  you can get the form data as JSON using

```
$('form').serializeArray()
```

take a look at this example I threw together [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/t7o6pkur/2/)

Comment: I just edited, forget the upload, the main problem is the json result. Ii have added a sample of what I want

Comment: @dbkonXepts I just updated my answer with .serializeArray() that will let you get the form data as JSON, along with a link to a fiddle to test out / experiment with.  Let me know how it works out and if you need more help with it.

Comment: Cool, can you create a sample for dynamically generated field, and show a json result. I wont mind an array example too. And that will be all

Comment: @dbkonxepts heres a quick fiddle example (very basic / simple).  Does this help at all?  https://jsfiddle.net/t7o6pkur/4/ ?  (I don't know WHY this answer got a down vote, not saying its 100% perfect, just trying to help you find your way to the solution to your issue.)

Comment: No it doesn't as the fields are not dynamically generated.

Comment: the fields are generated and added to the form from an array of questions, I must not be understanding what you're looking for, sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133722/discussion-between-dbkonxepts-and-tamak).